# Multiple conditions for IfCondition in ros2 launch script

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to launch a node in a ros2 launch script that requires multiple conditions i.e. a logical 'and' expression

```
DeclareLaunchArgument("input_arg", default_value="arg1")
DeclareLaunchArgument("bool_arg", default_value="false")

input_arg = LaunchConfiguration("input_arg")
bool_arg = LaunchConfiguration("bool_arg")

my_node = Node(
        package="my_pkg",
        executable="my_node",
        # condition=IfCondition(input_arg == arg2 and not bool_arg)
    )
```

I only want to launch the above node if the input_arg launch argument equals a specific value and the bool_arg argument is false. It easy enough to do one or the other condition e.g. with LaunchConfigurationEquals for the input_arg, but how do combine both these into one IfCondition. I'm guessing it has something with using PythonExpression but I can't get anything to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394181/multiple-conditions-for-ifcondition-in-ros2-launch-script/) by [thejeeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/54884/thejeeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2022-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's what finally worked for me. It is not very readable and the syntax is messy.

```
condition=IfCondition(
            PythonExpression(
                ["'", input_arg, "' == 'arg2' and '", bool_arg, "' == 'false'"]
            )
        ),
```

There doesn't seem to be much documentation on PythonExpression so it would be helpful to add some and possibly add support for multiple conditions.

---

Originally posted by [thejeeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/54884/thejeeb/) with karma: 118 on 2022-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Handling multiple conditions using the Launch.Condition wasn't built in from the start (see: https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/105), and I haven't seen movement on the repo to add the functionality yet...

A proposed workaround at the time was to use a PythonExpression substitution. Example [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/commit/59f9637c777f0d9b4e305715813aac67cf842305)

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2022-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thejeeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/54884/thejeeb/) on 2022-01-14**:
Thanks for the link. I had seen the ros2 launch issue which didn't get any traction and the nav2 example you linked. However, the nav2 example you linked didn't work for me. For example, the following for my example above does not work:

```
condition=IfCondition(
        PythonExpression(["'", input_arg, "' == 'arg2' and not ", bool_arg])
        ),
```

Instead, I found something more explicit that worked. See my answer.